# "OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long" while opening a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a number that is already in a text file with a new number. I opened the file and the name of the file I am opening is pretty short: "example_Na.chem", but I am still receiving the error that: OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long".

The code I am using is:

```
filename_chem = open('./input/example_Na/example_Na.chem', 'r').read()
input_file_chem = filename_chem.format(albeitSSA=albeitSSA)
    with open(filename_chem, 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(input_file_chem)
```

Comment: First, it's relevant which OS you're running on, as that is what determines the maximum length of the filename. Second, the filename length includes the full pathname, so the `/input/example_Na/example_Na.chem` is all part of the filename.

Comment: What OS are you doing this on?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering the question. @JGFMK I am using Linux 16.04.

Comment: @Ken White But I think the problem is the content of the file. It is a pretty long text file. After the error, it prints out the content of the text file.

Comment: Content of the text file will not cause a *File name too long* error. A file that was too large  would cause an *out of memory* error. Read the words in the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading the content of the file `./input/example_Na/example_Na.chem` and then using the file content as the file name for write-back, which can be too big for a file name. If you mean to write back the formatted content back to the same file you should open the same file name for writing instead:

```
filename_chem = open('./input/example_Na/example_Na.chem', 'r').read()
input_file_chem = filename_chem.format(albeitSSA=albeitSSA)
with open('./input/example_Na/example_Na.chem', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(input_file_chem)
```

Comment: Nice catch - I missed it. :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Leila You can open the same file name for writing as the file name your read from, like I show you above in the code.

Comment: @blhsing Thank you so much. That solved the problem. I am sorry I am a new user I cannot upvote your comments. But they were really useful. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I still have a problem. I defined a dictionary inside "example_Na.chem" and 100 values for "albeitSSA". I wrote the code this way to open the "example_Na.chem", replace the first value of albeitSSA, call a model inside the code and run that, and replace the 2nd value of albeitSSA in the "example_Na.chem". When I am using your approach, the 1st value of "albeitSSA" will be replaced with the dictionary that I defined in "example_Na.chem" and it does not go to the 2nd step to replace the 2nd value. Because it overwrite on the file!! Could you please let me know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: @Leila It's rather hard to understand what you're describing without seeing your code. Since this is a problem separate from the one in this question, can you post your new problem as a new question, so we can better help?